# How to process and update all models in a collection, in a single transaction, with Bookshelf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, bookshelf.js

I need to iterate over all the models in a Bookshelf collection, compute some information, then store that information back in each model. It's important that I do this in a single transaction, for rollbacks on errors.

The problem I am running into is the only way I can really think of to do this is with `Promise.map` (Bluebird), but a bookshelf collection can't be passed to map. For example, this does not work (`Thing` is a Model, `Promise` is a bluebird promise):

```
Bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return Thing.fetchAll({transacting:t}).then(function (things) {
        return Promise.map(things, function (thing) {
            return thing.save({
                value: computeSomeValueSync(thing)
            }, {
                transacting: t
            });
        });
    });
}).tap(function () {
    console.log("update complete");
});
```

Because `things` can't be passed to `Promise.map`, and there doesn't seem to be anything in the Bookshelf API that can obtain an array of models from a collection...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found *a* solution, at least.

First step is to write a function that computes *and* saves the value, and make it be a member of the bookshelf model. So, for the example from my post, I'd define the following function in `Thing` when extending the model:

```
... = bookshelf.Model.extend({

    ...

    updateSomeValue: function (options) {
        return this.save({ 
            value: computeSomeValueSync(this)
        }, options);
    }

});
```

Where `options` is the options to pass to save, which we can use to pass the transaction through. Easy enough. *Then*, we can do the equivalent of `Promise.map` with [`Collection#invokeThen`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-invokeThen), like this:

```
Bookshelf.transaction(function (t) {
    return Thing.fetchAll({transacting:t}).then(function (things) {
        return things.invokeThen("updateSomeValue", {transacting:t});
    });        
}).tap(function () {
    console.log("update complete");
});
```

There, `invokeThen` essentially does what I intended to do with `Promise.map` -- returns a promise that becomes fulfilled once all the promises returned by `Thing#updateSomeValue` are fulfilled.

It's only mildly inconvenient in that I have to add the model method, but it *does* make a bit of sense at least. The interface is a little weird because the docs are tough to piece together. But, at least it's possible.

Still open to other ideas.